# Set column indexes after moving a column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using a `JTable`, and I need to allow moving of its columns. But there comes the problem. Once they have rearranged, it's like just they have changed there content and title only. But I also need their indexes to be changed as well.

To make this more clear, I'll give an example. Let's say my first column is called "names". When calling the 'setName()' method, a name must always go to that column, no matter where the column is. But not to the first column..Hope you got my point!

I've finished writing required methods. Hope there is a way to achieve this without touching the finished methods.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To make this more clear, I'll give an example. Let's say my first column is called "names". When calling the 'setName()' method, a name must always go to that column, no matter where the column is. But not to the first column..Hope you got my point!

If you want to change the data, simply alter the underlying `TableModel` directly. The order of the columns never changes in the `TableModel`, it is only in the view (the `JTable`) that those columns are re-ordered.

If you do want to go through the table, you will have to convert from 'view-coordinates' to 'model-coordinates' by using the available `JTable#convertColumnIndexToModel` (view -> model) and the `JTable#convertColumnIndexToView` (model->view) methods as @MadProgrammer mentioned.

You should certainly not update the `setValueAt` method of the `TableModel` as you mentioned in one of your comments. As said before, the `TableModel` does not change the order of the columns, so the `setValueAt` should always be called with 'model coordinates', hence there is no need to transform those

Comment: Thanx. I'm almost there but I got no answer yet. @Robin, As you said i didn't touch my table model. Instead i did this, (think that's what you suggested)

For example, to set column 0 (consider rows are fixed)
    model.setValueAt("VALUE", row, table.convertColumnIndexToModel(0));

But it doesn't give what i want. I'm stuck here. please help. I have not much exp with jTables..

Comment: Alright, i got it. It was solely my fault. I should have tried before posting above comment. It works!! All i have to do is deal with the model when adding/removing values. yeah, that's what you said..Thanx Robin. (also thanx a lot @MadProgrammer. Both of you helped a lot. Have to mark this as the answer since it give more details, cz can't mark two answers...)

Comment: No worries, Robin's is a better explanation

Answer (score 4):

Oh yeah, I love this, it always gets me ;)

Check out [JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(int viewColumnIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29) and [JTable.convertColumnIndexToView(int modelColumnIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)

Essentially, you need convert the column index to and from the view index.

You shouldn't need to worry about this with the `TableModel` as it's taken care for you my the `JTable`.

You'll have a similar issue with the `RowSorter`

Comment: +1 For reference, "When using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates."—[*How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the additional link!

Comment: Well, thanx for the info. I tried what you said.(dunno whether i did it right). Yeah, it does something but it's not ok.
It will be much helpful if you can explain it with a small example.

Comment: I'd be happy, can you show me what you've done and what's not working so I have a better idea of the problem

Comment: Actually what i did was, i changed the 'setValueAt()' method of my table model.. :D. Well sorry,couldn't figure out other way. Is this correct? (guess not..) Then what should i do. Thanx a lot!!

Comment: As Robin pointed out, this should be fine, you shouldn't need to change the column index from that reported by the model